# Where and how was Diavolo hiding where he was after the body swaps of Silver Chariot Requiem?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind*, I don't understand the rules of the body/soul swap and where Diavolo was hiding during the soul swapping shenanigans of Silver Chariot Requiem.

1. Was Diavolo apparently hiding inside King Crimson who was attached as a summonable stand of Trish (along with Spice Girl)? If so this raises many other questions for me of such as
2. Why is it that King Crimson attached to Trish? Could King Crimson have happened have been attached to Trish, but could've been attached to anyone else as well? I would have assumed the stand to have been attached to the mind/soul as has been the case for the other swaps.
3. Why is Diavolo's "soul" inside King Crimson, a stand rather than a regular physical body like the other swaps (albeit Polnaroff is in a turtle transport MacGuffin that has stand...?)
4. Why didn't other souls get put into stands e.g. Giorno is inside Foo Fighters the airplane stand? My memory is foggy but I feel the question could be asked about how chaotic you want to make your swaps do every bullet in Sex Pistols count of a potential body then?

Or is it the case that split personality thing made it so Trish and Diavolo's mind/soul was in the Mista physical body she was inhabiting, and that King Crimson just has an innate perk of letting Diavolo inhabit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diavolo's Soul, which is attached to King Crimson, was "set free" by Silver Chariot Requiem.

Much like he shared a body with Doppio (without having full control), the same thing happened with Mista's body, now being inhabitted by the soul of Trish. Assuming Diavolo had no choice who he swapped with, this fact stands as mere coincidence.

Doppio had no idea he was being inhabited by the boss, therefore it stands to reason the same thing is true with Trish and her soul in Mista's body.

Using Mista's body & King Crimson, Diavolo managed to kill Narancia in Giorno's body undetected.

If you watch the scene, Mista seems to be the closest to where Giorno's body (inhabited by Narancia) was strung up.